# Detecting if a HttpModule is loaded

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpmodule

I'm trying to find a way to programmatically check if a particular HttpModule is loaded (as a component I'm writing requires the module to work correctly). I'm trying:

```
bool ismodulepresent = false;
foreach(HttpModuleAction module in ((HttpModulesSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpModules")).Modules)
{ 
    if(module.Type == typeof(MyModule).FullName)
    {
        ismodulepresent = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But that only works for the IIS5.1 `<httpModules>` section and not the newer `<system.webServer>` section.

Any idea if there is a better way to do this other than just checking both sections?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
HttpModuleCollection modules = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules;
foreach (string moduleKey in modules.Keys)
{
    IHttpModule module = modules[moduleKey];
    // Do your check here
}
```